# What is a polling mechanism in AWS SQS and how does it works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The published messages in SNS are getting to SQS queue. When I try to view the messages in the queue console displays **Start polling for messages**. I just want to know how this works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking this tutorial on how SQL works

> Amazon AWS provides SDKs for the most popular programming languages:
>   C++, Go, Java, JavaScript, .Net, Node.js, PHP, Python, and Ruby. You
>   can find them here.
>
> For SQS, the following automatic functionality is included:
>
> the cryptographic signing of your service requests retrying requests
>   handling error responses To integrate SQS with your app via API, you
>   will need to construct an Amazon SQS endpoint first, then make GET and
>   POST requests, and interpret responses. For detailed instructions,
>   refer to the SQS Developer Guide.

https://www.aws.ps/quick-start-to-sqs/

Answer (score 0):

As per [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-short-long-polling-differences) AWS SQS has both short and long polling mechanisms.
The difference between two  as per the documentation is :

> Short polling occurs when the WaitTimeSeconds parameter of a
>   ReceiveMessage request is set to 0 in one of two ways:
>
> ```
> The ReceiveMessage call sets WaitTimeSeconds to 0.
>
> The ReceiveMessage call doesn’t set WaitTimeSeconds, but the queue attribute ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds is set to 0.
> ```